# Dynamically looping through columns in sets to unpivot results

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a better way to create unpivoted views/tables based on sets of data and changing column counts. Test Date and Test Results need to stay together, but the file I get can change based on the max number of tests a particular patient has on that file. One file can have 150 patients and the max number of test would be 40, the next file I get could have 200 patients and the max number of tests could be 75.

Crude example of the data below:

| MRN | Dx Date | Test Date | Test Results | Test Date 1 | Test Results 1 | Test Date 2 | Test Result 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-02-12 | 2021-02-12 | 8.9 | 2021-02-19 | 9.3 | 2021-03-05 | 9.5 |
| 54321 | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 | 7.3 | 2020-12-19 | 7.8 | 2020-12-26 | 8.2 |
| 67890 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-15 | 9.2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Right now, I am creating a view that UNION ALL each result set. This is fine until they add another test date and test result number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MRN
    ,"Dx Date"
    ,"Test Date"
    ,"Test Result"
FROM
    Test Results

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
    MRN
    ,"Dx Date"
    ,"Test Date1"
    ,"Test Result1"
FROM
    Test Results
```

and so-on

Result:

| MRN | Dx Date | Test Date | Test Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-02-12 | 2021-02-12 | 8.9 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-12 | 2021-02-19 | 9.3 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-12 | 2021-03-05 | 9.5 |
| 54321 | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 | 7.3 |
| 54321 | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-19 | 7.8 |
| 54321 | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-26 | 8.2 |
| 67890 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-15 | 9.2 |

This is one of many tables that I need to unpivot. Surely there is a better way to do this dynamically that can loop through the column names (by set) and return the results in this format.

I went down the rabbit hole on this one and tried quite a few things to no avail. I queried the column names from the information_schema then created an array with the correct column sets but could not get that to work in the end.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please include code to reproduce test data in future posts, similar to what I have done below in my answer.  It makes it easier for contributors to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what your looking for, making use of semi-structured SQL and types to first flatten, then gather the relevant columns, and then extract the desired results.  This should handle any number of columns for test date/result as long as you adjust the wildcards to match the column-name pattern you have.

First create test data :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRANSIENT TABLE test_results 
( MRN INTEGER,
 "Dx Date" DATE,
 "Test Date" DATE,
 "Test Result" NUMERIC(12,2),  
 "Test Date 1" DATE,
 "Test Result 1" NUMERIC(12,2),
 "Test Date 2" DATE,
 "Test Result 2" NUMERIC(12,2)
 ) as
Select *
From (Values (12345, '2021-02-12', '2021-02-12', 8.9, '2021-02-19',  9.3, '2021-03-05', 9.5),
             (54321, '2020-12-12', '2020-12-12', 7.3, '2020-12-19',  7.8, '2020-12-26', 8.2),
             (67890, '2022-01-15', '2022-01-15', 9.2,         NULL, NULL,         NULL, NULL)
) as t1 ( MRN , "Dx Date","Test Date","Test Result","Test Date 1","Test Results 1","Test Date 2","Test Result 2" );
```

Now the SQL to get your result:

```
with 

  cte1 as 
  (Select 
     MRN , 
     "Dx Date",
     -- create an object containing key/value pairs for all columns in the row
     object_construct(*)  RESULT_OBJECT
   from test_results)
   
, cte2 as 
  (Select
      MRN , 
      "Dx Date",
      -- Adjust the wildcard filters here to make sure they capture 
      -- the variety of Date and Result column names in your actual data 
      array_agg(iff(upper(KEY) like '%DATE%' , VALUE, Null)) date_values,
      array_agg(iff(upper(KEY) like '%RESULT%' , VALUE, Null)) result_values 
   From cte1
        -- Use lateral flatten to unpivot the object to rows 
        ,lateral flatten (input => cte1.RESULT_OBJECT) FR
   Where
          -- This filter ensures that your pivot key columns
          -- that were also captured in the object_construct(*)
          -- aren't included in the aggregated arrays of test 
          -- dates/results
          (fr.KEY not in ('MRN','Dx Date') )
   group by all          
   )
   
select 
   MRN , 
   "Dx Date",
   VALUE::DATE "Test Date",
   -- Use index of flattened Test Date array to retrieve corresponding result_value from it's array
   result_values[INDEX]::NUMERIC(12,2) "Test Result"
from cte2, lateral flatten (input => DATE_VALUES)
order by 1,2
;
```